# Usage of iconv function in R to transliterate German words

Tags: r, locale, diacritics, iconv, transliteration

I am trying to use the `iconv` function in R to achieve the correct transliteration of German words (for example, *Möbel* → *Moebel*).

I have written the following code (tried with English/German locales):

```r
iconv("Möbel", "latin1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "Mobel"

iconv("Möbel", "UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] NA

iconv("Möbel", "UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", sub ="")
[1] "Mbel"

iconv("Möbel", "Windows-1252", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "Mobel"
```

However, this is not working properly. Here is the output of some of my tests:

```r
#cat + library(ds4psy)
iconv(cat ("M", Umlaut["o"],"bel", sep = ""), "latin1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
Möbelcharacter(0)
```

```r
#paste/paste0 + library(ds4psy)
> iconv(paste ("M", Umlaut["o"],"bel", sep = ""), "latin1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "MA?bel"
```

For completeness, I also tried the function `stri_trans_general` from `stringi`:

```r
stri_trans_general("Möbel", "latin-ascii")
[1] "Mobel"
```

but, as you can see, this didn't work, either.

What I don't understand is why the `iconv` function is not working properly in R when it clearly works correctly in [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php):

```php
<?php
    //some German
    $utf8_sentence = 'Weiß, Goldmann, Göbel, Weiss, Göthe, Goethe und Götz';
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
    
    $trans_sentence = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf8_sentence);
    
    //gives [Weiss, Goldmann, Goebel, Weiss, Goethe, Goethe und Goetz]
    echo $trans_sentence . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Why am I seeing this difference in behavior with the `iconv` version in R vs. PHP? What am I doing wrong in my R code?

Comment: the one that returned `NA` was the closest to the working PHP one. If I were you, I would do a string replace (I have no idea how to do that in R) of `ä`→`ae` etc.

Comment: @WalterTross Yes, we can do it with ```regex```. f.e.: ```> str_replace("Möbel", "ö", "oe")
[1] "Moebel"``` But how to fix ```iconv```, interesting.

Comment: @WalterTross You are welcome, question was reopened. I really don't know, where is this function broken. Or i use it wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If it isn't necessary that you use `iconv`, there is another way to achieve your goals.

You can define a set of German characters you want to transliterate and a set of their replacements and use these pairs as input for `str_replace_all`:

Data:

```
gg <- c("Göthe", "gerädert", "Hürde", "weiß")
```

First, define your sets:

```
set <- setNames(c("oe", "ae", "ue", "ss"),
                c("ö", "ä", "ü", "ß"))
```

Then replace:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(gg, set)
[1] "Goethe"    "geraedert" "Huerde"    "weiss"
```